# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php

I cannot see what the issue is with this line:

```
$imagepath = $dirPath.'\files\images\profile\people\';
```

I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''\files\images\profile\people\' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

What am I missing?

Comment: Escape your backslashes - they have special meanings in strings and `\'` is an escaped `'` symbol - not a backslash followed by a `'`.

Comment: Thanks.  Duh.  My bad.